# Successor to Square's Tape for persistent queues on Android

Tags: android, persistence, square, square-tape

https://square.github.io/tape/

Is there modern alternative to Square's Tape library for implementing persistent queues on Android? I notice Tape hasn't been upgraded in a while, but trying to search for other solutions to the problem all seem to lead back to Tape.

Trying to avoid implementing a queue backed by SQLite manually, but also wary of using a library which hasn't been updated in 5 years.